# Creating yii migration from demo blog sql

Tags: php, sql, yii, sqlmigrations

I have a SQL code from yii demo blog:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_post
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    tags TEXT,
    status INTEGER NOT NULL,
    create_time INTEGER,
    update_time INTEGER,
    author_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_post_author FOREIGN KEY (author_id)
        REFERENCES tbl_user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO tbl_lookup (name, type, code, position) VALUES ('Draft', 'PostStatus', 1, 1);
```

I need to write it to a file migration in a function up(), how to write the code?
And where can I read about the addition of tables in the migration file (I mean how to write, for example "varchar" or "string")?
Is it possible to add a file migration "INSERT", "UPDATE"?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMigration#createTable-detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your function up() or safeUp() you would add the following code:

```
$this->createTable('tbl_post', array(
  "id" => "pk",
  "title" => "VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL",
  "content" => "TEXT NOT NULL",
  "tags" => "TEXT",
  "status" => "INT NOT NULL",
  "create_time" => "INT",
  "update_time" => "INT",
  "author_id" => "INT NOT NULL",
), "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci");

$this->addForeignKey('FK_post_author', 'tbl_post', 'author_id', 'tbl_user', 'id', 'CASCADE', 'RESTRICT');

$this->insert('tbl_lookup', array(
  "name" => "Draft",
  "type" => "PostStatus",
  "code" => 1,
  "position" => 1,
);
```

There is an update() method available as well (insert has been shown above):
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMigration#update-detail